# How to iterate a dataframe and insert into mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Assuming I have a dataframe called *df* which looks like the one shown below:

My data frame table is below

```
Place      uid     sal  
NY         9999    4322
Berlin     1343    3234
NY         22      3234
Berlin     134     3234
```

My psql frame is below

```
Id      Place      uid    flag
1        NY        22     1
2       Berlin     134    1
3       Paris      432    0
4       Paris      43     0
5       Berlin     556    0
```

I need to insert the psql table flag by comparing with dataframe `uid`

- if flag=1 of particular uid it wont update.

From the data frame `uid=9999,1343` will only insert because in psql both flag is zero

Basically it will check the uid of dataframe whether it is present or not if flag is 1 it wont insert and flag is zero then it will update to `1` if uid is not there then it will insert with flag as `0`

Comment: can I request a tiny bit more info? Are you attempting to insert your dataframe into a SQL table, but only if the related flag in the other table is 1?

Comment: @houseofleft    Basically it will check the uid of dataframe whether it is present or not if flag is 1 it wont insert and flag is zero then it will update to 1 if uid is not there then it will insert with flag as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a few different ways, but probably the easiest would be to start with a merge.

Bring your dataframes together with a left join of the data you want to write to SQL:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='uid')
```

Then I'd just filter that dataframe so the flags of 1 are removed

```
merged_df = merged_df[merged_df['flag'] != 1]
```

and write the columns you want to sql:

```
merged_df[['Place', 'uid', 'sal']].to_sql('sql_table', con_engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

(the con_engine, df1 and df2 are all psuedo-code, but shouldn't be too tricky to fill in)

edit: I've just seen that you mentioned adding in a flag for the blank flags, you could do that with an apply if you were wondering:

```
merged_df['flag'] = merged_df['flag'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 1 else 0)
```